# what happened when using the same variable in two layer loops in python?

Tags: python, scope

I test the following code:

```
for i in range(3):
    for i in range(3,5):
        print "inner i: %d"%(i)
    print "outer i: %d"%(i)
```

and the output is:

```
inner i: 3
inner i: 4
outer i: 4
inner i: 3
inner i: 4
outer i: 4
inner i: 3
inner i: 4
outer i: 4
```

I don't understand why in the outer loop the `i` is 4 but the outer loop still runs for 3 times. It seems that the  the variable `i` in the `print "outer i: %d"%(i)` line is the `i` in the inner loop , but when goes to the `for i in range(3)` it uses the i in the outer loop.

Anyone can explain this? It's a little confusing to me now.

Comment: Why are you using the same variable name in each loop anyway?

Comment: Changing the value of `i` in the inner loop does not change the amount of times you can iterate over `range(3)` of the outer loop.

Comment: @Sayse I just saw a code snippet and it use the same variable in two loops and the code still runs in the right way. so I test it myself  to see what happened

Answer (score 13):

It's *the same `i`, Python doesn't have block scope*. At the beginning of each for-loop iteration, you assign the the next value in the iterator to `i`. Python for-loops aren't like C/Java for-loops, they are *foreach* loops. The continue until the iterator is exhausted (or you `break` out somehow). A for-loop is equivalent to the following while-loop:

```
iterator = iter(my_iterable)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    do_stuff(x)
```

So, your nested loop is the equivalent of this:

```
it1 = iter(range(3))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(it1)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    it2 = iter(range(3, 5))
    while True:
        try:
            i = next(it2)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        print "inner i: %d"%(i)

    print "outer i after: %d"%(i)
```

Note, a C/Java for-loop, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++){
    do_stuff(i);
}
```

Would be in Python:

```
i = 0
while i < stop:
   do_stuff(i)
   i += 1
```

In other words, the classic-for-loop depends on `i`, that is, the termination condition depends on the value of `i`. But in a for-each loop, the termination condition depends on the *iterator*. And it doesn't matter what you do to the variable *inside the body*, at the beginning of each iteration, it is assigned the next value of the iterator.

Comment: if it's the same `i` it'll have same `id` right, it's not

Comment: @VanPeer no, `id` belongs to the *object*, not the variable. The same variable can reference different objects at any given time.

Answer (score 6):

In the inner loop you are assigning a different variable to i. Since it is the same variableit always prints 4 (the last value i was assigned in the inner loop.
However, when you go to the next iteration of outer loop it will be set to the next value (i.e. 2 for the second outer loop).
You should print outer loop before the inner loop to see the effect more clearly:

```
for i in range(3):
    print "outer i before:%d"%(i)
    for i in range(3,5):
        print "inner i: %d"%(i)
    print "outer i after: %d"%(i)
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did to see the effect. I think the value (counter) of the outer loop is being kept in the program memory by Python, and then it reassigns it to the proper variable. Though, I'm not sure about that deep into Python, so if someone knows, please clarify :)

Comment: A for-loop ends when the iterator is done. So, the outer loop ends after 3 cycles. It does not depend on the ‘i’

Answer (score 3):

Notice how the output is always

```
inner i: 3
inner i: 4
outer i: 4
```

for every outer loop.

The program takes the final value of `i` in each iteration.

ie. when the outer loop starts execution, `i` is either 0, 1 or 2 but the value of `i` is modified in the inner for loop, which is getting printed.

Update:

```
for i in range(3):
    for i in range(3,5):
        print (id(i))
    print (id(i))
```

Output

```
1372154016
1372154032
1372154032
1372154016
1372154032
1372154032
1372154016
1372154032
1372154032
```

Comment: Cos, very `pythonic answer !`

Comment: This may not be proving what you think it might be, unless you understand all the reasons why "x = 1; y = 0+1; id(x) == id(y)" is True, while "x = 1001; y = 1000+1; id(x) == id(y)" is False.

Comment: @PeterHansen thanks for sharing this! it's `True` because the value (0) is not going to overlap; same goes with an empty string, which is not the case in the latter.

Comment: @VanPeer I'm not sure what "not going to overlap" means here, but note that I could equally well have said "x = 4; y = 3+1; id(x)==id(y)" is True. Would that change what you said? (And, if not, please clarify what the overlap bit refers to.)

Comment: @PeterHansen I got your point now; for the same reason why `x = 256; y = 255 + 1; id(x) == id(y)` is True and `x = 257; y = 256 + 1; id(x) == id(y)` is False. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's only one `i`, not two.  When the inner loop is entered, it changes `i`, and keeps changing it until the inner loop exits.  The next iteration of the outer loop then sets `i` to the next value in its range, but you never see it because you immediately enter the inner loop once more, again changing `i`.

This is of course very bad practice.  You should never modify the variable in a `for` loop while that loop is active.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Everything in this response is 100% true, and it fully explains the observed behavior.  Have the courage to leave a comment and identify yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Its the same i being used in both loops. When the outer loops gets a chance to print i, it will always have the last assigned value from the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Check @heltonbiker answer :

```
>>> for i in range(3):
    print "1-",locals()
    for i in range(3,5):
        print "2-",locals()


1- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 0, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
2- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 3, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
2- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 4, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
1- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 1, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
2- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 3, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
2- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 4, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
1- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 2, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
2- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 3, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
2- {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 4, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>>
```

**You read `i` data on wrong time (place)!**

If there is a single `BUS` or `Variable name` You must use the `FIFO` method.

[FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)  << Here information