# Nested loops where inner loop variable depends on outer loop variable, Python

Tags: python, loops

In Java, if I want to create nested loops where the inner loop variable depends on the outer loop variable (e.g. in typical bubble sort implementations), I can do something like this:

```java
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
     for(int j=i; j < n; j++){
         // Do something, e.g compare elements at index i and j
     }
}
```

What's the most "Pythonic" way to accomplish this in Python? I'm having trouble when I try to set the inner loop variable to the outer loop variable. For example, this doesn't work:

```
for i in range(n):
     for j=i in range(n):
         # Do something, e.g compare elements at index i and j
```

Comment: What is "do something"?  In Python you often don't need to do this at all because you can do something better instead (for instance something like `itertools.combinations`).  But it depends what you're actually doing in the loop.

Comment: Please not, that Python for-loops do not work like Java/C-style for-loops. Most of the time it can replace a c-style loop, but not always (at least, cleanly). They work like java for-each loops. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348171/5014455) to a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        #do something
```

Comment: Can these loops be vectorized ? One problem I see is that he inner loop init value depends on outer loop. So fundamentally I see these loops as being not vectorizable.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the Python equivalent of a `for(i = a;i < b;i++)` loop is `for i in range(a, b)`. Applying this to your problem, you get

```
for i in range(0, n): # usually just range(n), but for consistency
  for j in range(i, n):
    # stuff
```

Comment: Yes, this is in my opinion closest to the what the OP wants while also staying Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

In your added comment, you say you want to "compare elements at index i and j".  In general it is not Pythonic to use `for` loops to loop over an *index*.  Instead, just loop over the elements.  This can be done for instance with `itertools.combinations` in some circumstances.  Don't do this:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(some_list)):
        compare(some_list[i], some_list[j])
```

Instead, do this:

```
for item1, item2 in itertools.combinations(some_list, 2):
    compare(item1, item2)
```

Whether you can do this in your specific case depends on what you're doing.  But the point is that in Python, before trying to write a loop over indices, you should first think whether you can just write a loop over the elements, and eliminate the indices altogether from your code.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it as the following:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
     j = i
     while j < n:
          # something
           j += 1
      i += 1
```

Comment: You can, but that's not very pythonic.